# Una consulta SQL o muchas en una linea para mas eficiencia (optimización)

Tags: mysql, sql, optimización

soy nuevo en esto de las base de datos, si bien no tengo problemas con las consultas, me gustaría saber de que manera se hacen mas eficientemente cuando la DB tiene que interactuar con ellas.

Por ejemplo, cual de las siguientes 2 consultas es la mas óptima?

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (value 1.1, value1.2);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (value 2.1, value2.2);
```

Ó...

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (value 1.1, value1.2),
                         (value 2.1, value2.2);
```

Otro ejemplo que me interesa mucho es el SELECT, estoy desarrollando una aplicación web donde tengo que buscar en la base de datos elementos que coincidan con las palabras que ingreso el usuario. Si bien lo estoy desarrollando en Django (por lo que la sintaxis va a ser diferente) me gustaría saber cual de las dos consultas es mejor

```
SELECT atributeA FROM table WHERE atributeB LIKE %palabra1%;
SELECT atributeA FROM table WHERE atributeB LIKE %palabra2%;
....
SELECT atributeA FROM table WHERE atributeB LIKE %palabra20%;
```

Ó...

```
SELECT atributeA FROM table WHERE atributeB LIKE %palabra1% OR atributeB = LIKE %palabra2% OR .... atributeB = LIKE %palabra20%;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INSERT**

En cuanto a los `insert`, me imagino que combinarlo todo en un `insert` puede ser mas eficiente, pero no creo que la diferencia sea enorme, si es que hay.

En otras bases de datos, como SQL Server, puede ser mas eficiente combinar los `insert` cuando tu tabla tiene un `insert` trigger, para evitar que se ejecute para cada registro insertado. Pero, si no me equivoco, en MySQL, los triggers se ejecutan por registro de todas maneras.

Otra consideración es si tu base de datos se encuentra en un diferente servidor del programa que efectua las consultas. De ser el caso, combinar los `insert` puede ahorrarte el tiempo que toma en comunicar con la base de datos por el network. Cuanto mas `insert` tengas, más se notará la diferencia, por más rápida que sea la comunicación con tu base de datos.

**SELECT**

Pero en cuanto al `select`, definitivamente deberías combinarlos si es posible.

Sobre todo, debido a que tus consultas tienen condiciones del estilo `LIKE '%palabra1%'`, esto significa que la consulta seguramente necesita hacer un scan completo de la tabla (una operación muy costosa) para devolver los resultados. Con varias consultas, cada consulta necesita hacer el scan completo de la tabla.

Pero con una sola consulta que combina todas las condiciones, un solo scan será necesario para satisfacer todas las condiciones de un solo. De modo que el rendimiento debería ser mucho mejor.

En cualquier caso, te sugiero que hagas los ensayos tu mismo y que compares las diferentes opciones con una buena cantidad de datos para poder observar las diferencias en rendimiento.

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Muchas gracias! Cuando pueda voy a ver como hago para testear, porque por el momento la DB tiene pocos registros y se complica conseguir un ambiente propicio para un testeo real